# Oledbconnection execute commad query error vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using VS2012 wpf application vb.net MS Access 2010. I'm tring to execute query via `oledbconnection` and it's return an error, but when I execute the same query via MS Access 2010 it returns table without any problem. What is wrong?

**Query:**

```
SELECT Agents.[PF], Agents.[User_ID], Agents.[First_Name], Agents.[Second_Name], Agents.[Third_Name], Agents.[Family_Name], Agents.[Gender], Agents.[Contract_Type], Agents.Area, Teams.Team_Name, Agents.Hiring_Date, Resignation_Pool.Resignation_Date, Resignation_Pool.Effective_Date, Replace(IIf(Skills.Skill_Directory Is Null,'','Directory, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_TRC Is Null,'','TRC, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Prepaid Is Null,'','Prepaid, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Postpaid Is Null,'','Postpaid, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_KeyAccount Is Null,'','KeyAccount, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Blackberry Is Null,'','Blackberry, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Broadband Is Null,'','Broadband, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Concierge Is Null,'','Concierge, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_ISP Is Null,'','ISP, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_Mada Is Null,'','Mada, ')+IIf(Skills.Skill_CSCS Is Null,'','CSCS, ')+'$',', $','') AS Skills FROM ((Agents INNER JOIN Resignation_Pool ON Agents.PF = Resignation_Pool.PF) LEFT JOIN Teams ON Agents.Team =  Teams.ID) LEFT JOIN Skills ON Agents.PF = Skills.PF WHERE Agents.Contract_Status = 'Active'
```

**Error:**

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

**Code:**

```
            Dim SQL10 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Agents.[PF], Agents.[User_ID], Agents.[First_Name], Agents.[Second_Name], Agents.[Third_Name], Agents.[Family_Name], Agents.[Gender], Agents.[Contract_Type], Agents.Area, Teams.Team_Name, Agents.Hiring_Date, Resignation_Pool.Resignation_Date, Resignation_Pool.Effective_Date, " & Sql & " FROM ((Agents INNER JOIN Resignation_Pool ON Agents.PF = Resignation_Pool.PF) LEFT JOIN Teams ON Agents.Team =  Teams.ID) LEFT JOIN Skills ON Agents.PF = Skills.PF WHERE Agents.Contract_Status = 'Active'")
            Dim DataAdapter10 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL10)
            Dim DataTable10 As New DataTable()
            DataAdapter10.Fill(DataTable10)
```

Comment: The problem is not with your query but with your `Command` Object that has not been properly set with your connection. Read the error carefully `:)`

Comment: could you please show us your code on how you are calling the query?

Comment: Check the command i edited the Q

Comment: This iif function for access2010 and its working in another query, and im using vb.net not VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that your OleDbDataAdapter has not its SelectCommand associated with a valid connection. Thus you should try to change your code in something like this

```
  Using OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("your_connection_string")
      connection.Open
      Dim SQL10 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("......", connection) ' add this to the OleDbCommand'
      Dim DataAdapter10 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL10)
      Dim DataTable10 As New DataTable()
      DataAdapter10.Fill(DataTable10)
  End Using
```

Comment: Thanks i know that i missed something, Thanks for helping :D

Comment: My kudos go to @JW who spotted the problem immediately